# Remove the border-right from a widget

Tags: html, css, wordpress

There is a ugly border-right on each of the second flip box widgets on https://northventures.ch/#partners (On SECA & Sictic logo boxes).

I can't find the css code to delete the border.

I tried to solve it with the following code:

```
.elementor-element .elementor-widget-container {
    border-right: none !important;
}

.elementor-432 .elementor-element.elementor-element-0ad6b1a.elementor-column > .elementor-column-wrap > .elementor-widget-wrap 
{
    border-right: none !important;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inspected the page, and it seems that its not the `border-right` its the color of flipped box. So to fix this, do this.

```
.premium-flip-main-box{
margin-right: -11px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

I have checked this is working. 
Edit: Earlier it wasn't working the way wanted. Now it is. I recorded the video : https://nimb.ws/MGmzXN

Comment: done, but they still appear on my browser. Thanks for your response and help.

Comment: Hey I made some changes. Check now!!